# populate empty list elements with strings python

Tags: python, string, pandas, list

I have a dataframe which contians nested lists. Some of those lists are empty, or contain only whitespaces. e.g:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'example':[[['  ', ' '],['Peter'],['   ', ' '],['bla','blaaa']]]})
```

for my further operations they are not allowed to be empty and cannot be deleted. Is there a way to fill them with e.g. `'some_string`

i thought of something similar to
`df.example = [[[a.replace(' ','some_string')if all a in i =='\s'for a in i]for i in x] for x in df.example]`, but this yields an invalid syntax error, further it wouldnt just fill the list, but each whitespace in the list. 
Since i am still learning python, my idea of a solution might be too complicated or completely wrong.

i.e. the solution should look like:

```
     example
0   [[some_string], [Peter], [some_string], [bla, blaaa]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `apply`

**Ex:**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'example':[[['  ', ' '],['Peter'],['   ', ' '],['bla','blaaa']]]})
df["example"] = df["example"].apply(lambda x: [i if "".join(i).strip() else ['some_string'] for i in x])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                             example
0  [[some_string], [Peter], [some_string], [bla, ...
```

- **Note:** This will be slow if you data is very large because of the iteration.

Comment: Or `df.example = [[i if ''.join(i).strip() else ['some_string'] for i in x] for x in df.example]`